# Could not find "store", even if the root is wrapped in Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I have an SSR react-redux app. Where I have the main index.js file including the `App` Component wrapped in `Provider`.

But If I try to use connect in the `App` component it throws this error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)"
```

I've already checked out these solutions, and none is relevant to me.

[related 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032676/invariant-violation-could-not-find-store-even-though-root-is-wrapped-with-pr)

[related 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892553/could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props-of-connectapp)

[related 03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027360/connect-cannot-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props?rq=1)

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const app = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

export default app;
```

```js
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{})(App);
```

```js
// configureStore.js

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import login from './login/reducer.js';

const configureStore = () => {
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login
  });

  const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      : compose;

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

```js
// login/reducer.js

const initialState = { user: {} };

const currentUser = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

export default currentUser;
```

Here's the complete error from browser's console

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.
    at invariant (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:146050:15)
    at Connect.renderWrappedComponent (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:51859:58)
    at Connect.indirectRenderWrappedComponent (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:51855:21)
    at updateContextConsumer (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:70185:938)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:70212:2189)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:70889:349)
    at workLoop (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:70896:45)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:67381:102)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:67401:45)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:67417:126)
invariant @ bundle.js:146050
renderWrappedComponent @ bundle.js:51859
indirectRenderWrappedComponent @ bundle.js:51855
updateContextConsumer @ bundle.js:70185
beginWork @ bundle.js:70212
performUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:70889
workLoop @ bundle.js:70896
callCallback @ bundle.js:67381
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:67401
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:67417
replayUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:70757
renderRoot @ bundle.js:70918
performWorkOnRoot @ bundle.js:71100
performWork @ bundle.js:71082
performSyncWork @ bundle.js:71080
requestWork @ bundle.js:71056
scheduleWork @ bundle.js:71002
scheduleRootUpdate @ bundle.js:71138
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ bundle.js:71139
updateContainer @ bundle.js:71139
ReactRoot.render @ bundle.js:71169
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:71182
unbatchedUpdates @ bundle.js:71126
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ bundle.js:71182
hydrate @ bundle.js:71185
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:57511
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:52705
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:63
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:66
bundle.js:67495 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>.
warningWithoutStack @ bundle.js:67495
warnForDeletedHydratableElement @ bundle.js:69163
didNotHydrateContainerInstance @ bundle.js:69265
deleteHydratableInstance @ bundle.js:69882
popHydrationState @ bundle.js:69912
completeWork @ bundle.js:70494
completeUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:70849
performUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:70895
workLoop @ bundle.js:70896
renderRoot @ bundle.js:70911
performWorkOnRoot @ bundle.js:71100
performWork @ bundle.js:71082
performSyncWork @ bundle.js:71080
requestWork @ bundle.js:71056
scheduleWork @ bundle.js:71002
scheduleRootUpdate @ bundle.js:71138
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ bundle.js:71139
updateContainer @ bundle.js:71139
ReactRoot.render @ bundle.js:71169
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:71182
unbatchedUpdates @ bundle.js:71126
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ bundle.js:71182
hydrate @ bundle.js:71185
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:57511
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:52705
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:63
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:66
bundle.js:70552 The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:
    in Connect(App)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
```

Comment: Perhaps you can also post the code for configureStore()

Comment: @ClintonChau updated the question, please check now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace, it appears you're rendering `App`. However, `App` is wrapped by a `Provider` within a new component you're creating called `app`. Thus, when you try to render `App`, react-redux is correctly letting you know that `App` doesn't have a `store` associated with it.

For example, you should write this:

```
const MyAppWithStore = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<MyAppWithStore />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I don't see in your posted code where you're actually rendering the root Component, so the above is just an example that you will need to adapt.